# iOS: Service layer class implementation and usage pattern

Tags: ios

In my iOS application I am thinking of creating separate service classes for grouping related API's (Micro-services pattern). Example I will create UserService class to group API's related User class. This class would then be a calling component for Network layer for loading data from Server.

My query is if I have to call same API multiple times from a view Controller, Would it be appropriate to create new objects of UserService class for each request or UserService should be singleton with Tags to identify each request.

Comment: Will you be making the calls in parallel or in a series?

Comment: If in Parallel, why? If in Series, what's the need for singleton here?

Comment: also I think your question might be more suited to Software Engineering SE. Do see [their on-topic list](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). And remember, cross-site posting is frowned upon. If you believe SESE suits your question better than SO, delete the post from here and take it over there.